# How to sort a dataframe with a column of date and time?

Tags: r

I want to sort a dataframe by chronological order, this dataframe is next one:

```
1 2532712 BOGOTÁ, D.C.  FONTIBON       5 2016-10-15 00:00:00.000   479      0
2 2532712 BOGOTÁ, D.C.  FONTIBON       5 2016-10-15 01:00:00.000   983      0
3 2532712 BOGOTÁ, D.C.  FONTIBON       5 2016-10-15 03:00:00.000   909      0
4 2532712 BOGOTÁ, D.C.  FONTIBON       5 2016-10-15 02:00:00.000  1035      0
5 2532712 BOGOTÁ, D.C.  FONTIBON       5 2016-10-15 05:00:00.000   723      0
6 2532712 BOGOTÁ, D.C.  FONTIBON       5 2016-10-15 04:00:00.000   678      0
1 2532712 BOGOTÁ, D.C.  FONTIBON       5 2016-10-15 06:00:00.000   271
```

I want to sort it accordint to the time you see. So it would be 0-1-2-3-4-5-6 in the time.
What would you do? I have tried what appears in other answers of the topic.

The dput() is:

```
structure(list(cliente = c("2532712", "2532712", "2532712", "2532712", 
"2532712", "2532712", "2532712", "2532712", "2532712", "2532712", 
"2532712", "2532712", "2532712", "2532712", "2532712", "2532712", 
"2532712", "2532712", "2532712", "2532712", "2532712", "2532712", 
"2532712", "2532712"), municipio = c("BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOGOTÁ, D.C.", 
"BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOGOTÁ, D.C.", 
"BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOGOTÁ, D.C.", 
"BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOGOTÁ, D.C.", 
"BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOGOTÁ, D.C.", 
"BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOGOTÁ, D.C.", 
"BOGOTÁ, D.C.", "BOGOTÁ, D.C."), localidad = c("FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", 
"FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", 
"FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", 
"FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", 
"FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", "FONTIBON", "FONTIBON"), estrato = c("5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", 
"5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5", "5"), fecha_hora = c("2016-10-15 00:00:00.000", 
"2016-10-15 01:00:00.000", "2016-10-15 02:00:00.000", "2016-10-15 03:00:00.000", 
"2016-10-15 04:00:00.000", "2016-10-15 05:00:00.000", "2016-10-15 06:00:00.000", 
"2016-10-15 15:00:00.000", "2016-10-15 16:00:00.000", "2016-10-15 17:00:00.000", 
"2016-10-15 18:00:00.000", "2016-10-15 19:00:00.000", "2016-10-15 20:00:00.000", 
"2016-10-15 21:00:00.000", "2016-10-15 22:00:00.000", "2016-10-15 23:00:00.000", 
"2016-10-15 07:00:00.000", "2016-10-15 08:00:00.000", "2016-10-15 09:00:00.000", 
"2016-10-15 10:00:00.000", "2016-10-15 11:00:00.000", "2016-10-15 12:00:00.000", 
"2016-10-15 13:00:00.000", "2016-10-15 14:00:00.000"), valor = c("479", 
"983", "909", "1035", "723", "678", "423", "150", "255", "446", 
"370", "250", "320", "227", "348", "219", "192", "210", "271", 
"155", "176", "277", "397", "247"), estado = c("0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", 
"0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0", "0")), .Names = c("cliente", 
"municipio", "localidad", "estrato", "fecha_hora", "valor", "estado"
), row.names = c(NA, -24L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
))
```

Comment: Have you checked https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1296646/ ? What did not work? The structure of your data is not 100% clear. It would be better to provide a `dput` of the data.

Comment: Seems duplicate: [How to sort a data frame by date in R](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246159/how-to-sort-a-data-frame-by-date-in-r).

Comment: Note that your date/time column is of class `character`. First you need to convert it to `POSIXct`. `dat$fecha_hora <- as.POSIXct(dat$fecha_hora)`. Then use the code in the links above.