# R - Date Sorting

Tags: r

I am having the data set filtered from from other data base, which is as below

```
        Date| freq
____________|_________
 01-Aug-2017| 3079
 02-Aug-2017| 3239
 03-Aug-2017| 3026
 04-Aug-2017| 2700
 05-Aug-2017|  846
 05-Jul-2017| 2647
 06-Aug-2017|  579
 07-Aug-2017| 3145
 08-Aug-2017| 3386
 09-Aug-2017| 3350
 10-Aug-2017| 3127
 11-Aug-2017| 2824
 12-Aug-2017|  784
 12-Jun-2017| 2359
 13-Aug-2017| 575
 13-Jun-2017| 2074
 14-Aug-2017| 3258
 14-Jun-2017| 2022
 15-Aug-2017| 2948
 15-Jun-2017| 2143
```

Sorting is not happening as per the date, but as per the characters. I tried to convert the date format with  as.Date but not successful. It will be a great help, to convert the date in any format and sort it date wise.
Any support in this direction will be a great help.

Thanks,
Praveen

Comment: Please show us the code that you are trying

Comment: Try somethinkg like `yourData$newDates <- as.Date(yourData$Date, "%d-%b-%Y")`

Comment: Or just `yourData[order(as.Date(yourData$Date, format = "%d-%b-%Y")), ]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to sort a data frame by date](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6246159/how-to-sort-a-data-frame-by-date)

Comment: Thanks for your support.. this has helped a lot :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let assume your dataframe is named 'd'
Apply code to sort according to dates:

```
d[order(as.Date(d$V3, format="%d/%m/%Y)),]
```

Comment: In this case, we need to use `format = "%d-%b-%Y"` instead of `format = "%d/%m/%Y"`. [This](http://www.statmethods.net/input/dates.html) can help to understand the specification of dates format.

Comment: Yes in the above case we can use "%d-%b-%Y" format.