# Convert character to Date and sort by Date in R

Tags: r, sorting, date

I have a csv file which has date in following format.

`date<-c("2018-08-11 03-PM","2018-02-11 05-AM","2018-08-11 01-AM")`

How can I convert it to Date in order to sort them by day and time?

Comment: Once they're of type `Date`, just sort as you'd sort any variable: [How to sort a data frame by date](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6246159/8366499)

Comment: It looks I can't set the time correct and get "2018-08-11 01-AM" before "2018-08-11 03-PM". Thoughts?

Comment: Parsing dates and times is really finicky. It's probably not understanding the "hour-AM/PM" properly. Take a look at `?lubridate::parse_date_time` for all the different format codes you can use. You might have to play around a bit to get it to read it properly. For the time part, you might want something like: `"... H-Op"`

Answer (score 0):

One line solution-

```
date<-sort(as.Date(c("2018-08-11 03-PM","2018-02-11 05-AM","2018-08-11 01-AM")))
```

**Edit:**

you need to remove `-` from time part-

```
date <- stringi::stri_replace_last_fixed(date, '-', ' ')
sort(lubridate::ydm_h(date))
```

Comment: but this only show date without time, I am thinking to write like ` date<-sort(as.Date(c("2018-08-11 03-PM","2018-02-11 05-AM","2018-08-11 01-AM"),format="%d/%m/%Y%H"))` but it does not work

Comment: Check above solution!!